# Alternate indentation display in Vim

Tags: vim

I came across this question: 
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/87077/how-can-a-code-editor-effectively-hint-at-code-nesting-level-without-using-inde
and thought that Vim might be able to do something similar as well with a plugin.

I believe the indentation level could be indicated with the a sign (icon in GUI, text with highlighting in term).  The piece I'm not sure about is displaying the lines without indentation.  Does anyone know, is it possible and/or how you would do it?

This question is not whether or not displaying indentation levels in this manner is desirable; but how to accomplish it in Vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `conceal` feature that is new in 7.3.

Here is a function that does roughly what the article is describing (for spaces; accounting for tabs instead would be a fairly trivial addition):

```
function! IndentationHeatMap()
    set conceallevel=1
    for i in range(1,9)
        let indentation = repeat(" ", &sts * i)
        exe 'syntax match NonText "^' . indentation . '" conceal cchar=' . i
    endfor
endfunction
```

A solution closer to what you are requesting might use `conceal` to hide *all* leading whitespace with

`syntax match NonText "^\s\+" conceal`

and then use `signs` to provide the indicators based on custom calculations.

Note: `NonText` in these syntax commands is an arbitrary highlight group.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect.  Did not know about the conceal feature before.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these plugins: [Indent Guides](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3361) and [IndentHL](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1800)
Both have screenshots.

Comment: These are the opposite of what I want to replicate.  I am trying to not show the indentation in the file itself; rather have the all the text lined up along the leftmost column.  Then in the "signs" column of vim use a fixed width indicator of the indentation level.